# du not respecting its own flag?

Tags: disk-usage

Despite the following help directive:

```
root@Andromeda:/# du --help | grep -- -x
  -x, --one-file-system    skip directories on different file systems
```

The following inquiry proceeds with inspecting e.g. `/proc` that is a distinct filesystem

```
root@Andromeda:/# du -schx *
13M bin
104M    boot
4,0K    cdrom
0   dev
16M etc
85G home
0   initrd.img
0   initrd.img.old
802M    lib
4,0K    lib64
16K lost+found
28K media
4,0K    mnt
324M    opt
du: cannot access 'proc/8303/task/8303/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/8303/task/8303/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/8303/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/8303/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
```

Why?

```
root@Andromeda:/# mount | grep -i proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/639086/334516

Comment: What you wanted is `du -schx .`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wildcard `*` character is expanded by the shell before `du` is invoked. Therefore `du` sees something like this:

```
du -schx bin boot dev etc home initrd.img lib lib64 lost+found media mnt opt proc root run sbin selinux srv sys tmp usr var vmlinuz
```

The `du` command honours the `-x` flag and agrees to skip files on different filesystems. It then sets off. First it processes `bin`. Then it processes `boot`. Then it processes `dev`. (You get the picture.) Later it processes `proc`. And so on until the end of the list.

Notice here that the `-x` promise applies to files and filesystems within the file trees it's searching (it has nothing to do with the current directory). So although `proc` is on its own filesystem, that's irrelevant: `du` will only skip files and directories *within `proc`* that are on different filesystems.

If you had gone for `du -xs /` then `/proc`, `/sys`, and other filesystems mounted under `/` would have been skipped.